# Endomorphisms of Artinian modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The following claim is from a paper [On the moduli spaces of bundles on K3 surfaces, I, p. 358] of Mukai. Consider an artinian module $\mathrm{M}$ over a local ring, and let $\mathrm{M}_0$ be the submodule of all $x\in\mathrm{M}$ annhilated by the maximal ideal of the local ring. Then every endomorphism of $\mathrm{M}$ preserves $\mathrm{M}_0$, and the natural map
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{M},\mathrm{M})\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{M}/\mathrm{M}_0,\mathrm{M}/\mathrm{M}_0)$$
is surjective. I can't quite see why this map is surjective - this is not justified in the paper, so I may be missing something obvious here (a comment may be enough).

Comment: "preserves $M_0$" means "maps $M_0$ into $M_0$"?

Comment: You might provide the precise reference and page.

Comment: @YCor exactly. I have included the reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is false. Take $A=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$ and $M=\omega_A$. Then $\operatorname{Hom}(\omega,\omega)$ has length 3 and $\operatorname{Hom}(M/M_0,M/M_0)$ has length 4, so the natural map cannot be surjective.

Comment: @SWS Isn't Mohan's example also a counterexample for the "if and only if" part of that?